First order logics exercise 2
Here is the exercise:
theorem T6 {α : Type} {P Q : α → Prop} : 
  (∀ x, P x -> ¬ ∃ y, Q y) → ∃ x, ∀ y, Q y → ¬ P x := by
  intro h
  by_cases hP : ∃ x, P x
  { -- Case 1: There exists an `x` such that `P x` holds
    cases hP with
    | intro x HPx =>
      specialize h x
      specialize h HPx
      exists x
      intro y
      intro Hq
      have Hexists : ∃ y, Q y := Exists.intro y Hq
      have HFalse := h Hexists
      exact HFalse.elim
  }
  {
    -- Case 2: There is no `x` such that `P x` holds
    
  }

In case 2 we have:
α : Type
P Q : α → Prop
h : ∀ (x : α), P x → ¬∃ y, Q y
hP : ¬∃ x, P x
⊢ ∃ x, ∀ (y : α), Q y → ¬P x

Here I am stuck because we can't get x from anywhere and get rid of existence quantifier in the goal.
Please, help.

I have been able to prove it very simply and without classical rules, but with the added assumption that $\alpha$ is inhabited.  Can you do that?  --  You have not said the context of these exercises: can you change/adjust definitions and theorem statements, or are these supposed to be solved exactly as given?

Otherwise, along the same line, can you use the axiom (∀ x, p) -> (∃ x, p)?  That may be used in predicate logic over "a non-empty domain of discourse", corresponding to an inhabited α.

(BTW, how unfortunate this percolating of Unicode symbols in proof assistants: conflating source code and how to working with source code with pretty printing and presentation...  Programmer's maxim: if you cannot work with it in notepad with a standard keyboard, it's not good/it's not source code.)

Note, if you got this problem from a typical logic textbook, typical logicians often assume that there is at least one element in the structure, whereas, as Julio said, Lean does not.  I think this is just false when alpha is empty.

@JasonRute  To be clear, I haven't said anything about Lean specifically, while what I have said is that (to my knowledge) typically logicians only do that in the context of simple approaches to classical predicate logic.

(Edit: This answer is mostly written from a classical logic point of view, but your theorem is provable without classical axioms when written correctly in Lean.  Also, see terminology notes at the end.)
In first-order logic (a.k.a. predicate logic) there is a subtle design choice of whether you want to allow "empty domains of discourse".  If you do, this means there could be no objects period, or from a model theory standpoint, structures/models can be empty.  The following sorts of statements would be tautologies if the domain of discourse was assumed to be non-empty, but falsifiable otherwise:

$\exists x. x = x$
$\exists x. (P x \rightarrow P x)$
$(\forall x. P x) \rightarrow (\exists x. P x)$

In Lean, Coq, and other dependent type theories, we allow for empty types (like Empty), so the domain of discourse is not assumed to be non-empty.  But in typical undergraduate first-order logic (as taught in say Enderton), or typical infinite model theory (as taught in a graduate model theory course), one assumes the domain of discourse is non-empty.  In proof assistants like HOL-Light or Isabelle/HOL, based on higher-order logic, the types are non-empty, and hence so is the domain of discourse.  (However, I've heard in computer science applications of (finite) model theory, like in model checking, you want to allow for empty models, hence allowing for an empty domain of discourse.)
So your theorem T6 is false in Lean.  If α was empty, then (∀ x, P x -> ¬ ∃ y, Q y) would be vacuously true (since ∃ y, Q y is false), but ∃ x, ∀ y, Q y → ¬ P x would be false.
A correct way to write it would be:
theorem T6 {α : Type} (h : Nonempty α) {P Q : α → Prop} : 
  (∀ x, P x -> ¬ ∃ y, Q y) → ∃ x, ∀ y, Q y → ¬ P x :=

Nonempty α says that there exists an element of α, and lets you prove things like ∃ (x : α), True.

Classical.exists_true_of_nonempty: Nonempty α → ∃ (x : α), True

(I don't know why the theorem is labeled Classical, as doesn't use any classical axioms.) The converse is also true:

nonempty_of_exists: (∃ (x : α), p x) → Nonempty α

So if it is easier for your exercise, you can instead assume ∃ (x : α), True.

Just to mention it, you can also write the theorem with the type classes Nonempty:
theorem T6 {α : Type} [Nonempty α] {P Q : α → Prop} : 
  (∀ x, P x -> ¬ ∃ y, Q y) → ∃ x, ∀ y, Q y → ¬ P x :=

The former is equivalent to the above but uses the type class system.

Update: An aside about terminology. To make it easier to understand and align with Lean's terminology, I've written my answer without being careful about constructive terminology.  In constructive logic, "non-empty" is not a good descriptor of "there exists an element of a type" (often called "inhabited"), since it isn't the same to say there exists an element and to say the type is not empty.
Further, what Lean calls Inhabited is a bit different (and what constructivists would call "pointed").  See Lean "nonempty" vs "inhabited" as well as Andrej's comment about terminology.  (Lean, despite having constructive foundations, is currently marketed towards classical logic, albeit with good support for computation, so sometimes it makes decisions which don't align with the constructive viewpoint.)

I was not talking about Inhabited in Lean, where I have said "inhabited" in the comments I meant in the type-theoretic sense, just synonym with "non-empty", and implicitly in the sense of the Curry-Howard correspondence between truthiness and inhabitancy, which is important for beginners to grasp, in particular as for "doing logic with proof assistants".

-1  It's useful to know what one can practically do in Lean in that sense, it is even more useful to find out how misnamed and misguided things are...  and the fact that you have systematically misrepresented what I have said is this thread is really the nail in that coffin.

@JulioDiEgidio, I understand misnamed. Andrej complains about the names Inhabited and Nonempty.  As for my answer, it is my point of view more than a summary of your comments. I borrowed “allow empty domain of discourse” since I couldn’t think of a  proof theoretic way to say it. (I would be inclined to say “allow empty model/structure” but that doesn’t sound relevant in this context.) As for misrepresenting, whether you meant Inhabited or not, the OP might have thought you did. I’ll edit.

@JulioDiEgidio, Also you can write your own answer (and keep my -1) if you feel my answer is more harmful than helpful.

Misreading me is not difficult apparently, so I won't hold a grudge about that, but 1) your tech answer is complementary to my explanations, but the latter can stay in the comments lacking any OP's feedback, and 2) (only for the expert, this is not cheap polemics) I do disagree, and not just in detail, rather with at least one century of "logic" that is the hijacking of Logic proper, and then three decades of the hijacking and subversion of everything "software/programming/applied logic", not to even mention the bigger picture...  Anyway, enough of that here.

@JulioDiEgidio I have to admit, I still don't really understand your complaint (especially concern (2)).  Is it that my answer is too classical and I'm not careful with my terminology? (I was trained as a logician in the model theory/set theory/computability theory camps which mostly avoid constructive concerns and assume models are nonempty, so my background is probably showing through.  But I also don't understand the anger I sometimes get from the constructive type theory community.)

You call it anger, I am just calling things by their name: that is a communication problem of some kind.  My point 2 is way beyond the scope here, but I am available if you like to have a chat about it, with you and whoever is interested.
